# Spring Session - SessionDestroyedEvent is not called

Tags: spring, redis, timeout, event-listener, spring-session

I have a Spring application where sessions are stored in redis with a short timeout (1m). I want to call a function after my sessions timeout, however SessionDestroyedEvent @EventListener does not get called.

SessionListener.java:

```
import org.springframework.context.event.EventListener;
import org.springframework.session.events.SessionCreatedEvent;
import org.springframework.session.events.SessionDestroyedEvent;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class SessionListener {

    @EventListener
    public void sessionCreated(SessionCreatedEvent event) {
        System.out.println("created"); // gets called
    }

    @EventListener
    public void sessionDestroyed(SessionDestroyedEvent event) {
        System.out.println("destroyed"); // never gets called

    }

}
```

application.properties:

```
spring.session.store-type=redis
server.servlet.session.timeout=1m
```

notes:

1. eventListener on SessionCreatedEvent gets called
2. sessions from redis disappear after the timeout

Answer (score 0):

Section [SessionDeletedEvent and SessionExpiredEvent](https://docs.spring.io/spring-session/docs/current/reference/html5/#api-redisoperationssessionrepository-sessiondestroyedevent) in Spring Session reference describes how sessions are cleaned up.

From the documentation:

> Firing `SessionDeletedEvent` or `SessionExpiredEvent` is made available through the `SessionMessageListener` which listens to *Redis Keyspace events*. In order for this to work, *Redis Keyspace events* for Generic commands and Expired events needs to be enabled